# What does (Pakyow::Presenter::MissingTemplate) mean?

Tags: pakyow

> .rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/pakyow-9d4d9be98b47/pakyow-presenter/lib/presenter/view_store.rb:105:in `template_with_name': No template named 'default' (Pakyow::Presenter::MissingTemplate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pakyow is looking for a template named `default.html` (in the `app/views/_templates` path unless you've changed your template path config option). If you're running on HEAD, this is likely being caused by a change to the default template name. In the last release, it was `pakyow`; now it's named `default`.